# Merge 2 objects in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an `items_controller.rb` and an `item_galleries_controller.rb`.

The `item_galleries` takes an `item_id`. Everything works great.

Since I'm using react I created a `presenter` object that sends the appropriate data to my redux store. My problem is I can't output the associated `item_galleries`.

This is my index method in the `items_controller.rb`:

```
  def index
    @items = Item.all
    @presenter = {
      :items => {
        :records => @items,
        :filtered => @items,
        :suggested => []
      }
    }
  end
```

I was able to get this to work and have the appropriate data output to json, but unfortunately the `jbuilder` is different from this `@presenter` object.

```
json.images items.item_galleries do |p|
    json.img url_for(p.image_url)
end
```

any idea on how to replicate above inside the index method and have it output along side the `@items`

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is I can't output the associated item_galleries

If `Item` has_many `:item_galleries` and `item_gallery`, `item_id` are columns on `:item_galleries` table then ...

```
#app/controllers/items_controller.rb
def index
  @items = Item.all
  ...
  @galleries = ItemGallery.where(item_id: @items.map(&:id))
end

#index.json.jbuilder
json.images @galleries do |gallery|
  json.img url_for(gallery.image_url)
end
```

Comment: how can I merge the galleries with the items though. so I can output in the @presenter.

Comment: `@items_galleries = Item.select('*').joins(:item_galleries)`

Comment: this is close, but now its just returning duplicate items that have multiple images attached to it.